# How to select element with id contain dot symbol in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I know maybe you think it's duplicate topic, but no; I tried these other recommended way but it didn't work to me.

I have a variable like this:

```
var $id = "test.1";
```

if I try to use the following line, it's worked:

```
$("#test\\.1")
```

but if I try to use `$('#'+'test\\.1')`, it doesn't work.

Could you please tell me why and how can I deal with it?

Update:
Sorry guys for the continuous edit the question. I will try to avoid it for the next questions.

So, this's my problem: 
http://jsfiddle.net/HzfLN/8/

I used:

```
var id = "text.1".replace(/[.]/gi, "\\\\");
$('#'+id).bind("click", function(){
   //Do my stuff
});
```

I tried to use 4 slash "\\" instead of "\". So I fixed it.

Thanks all your help.

Comment: FYI This is not valid in XHTML, but it is in HTML5, hope you are using right DOCTYPE

Comment: Please show us all the code.

Comment: `$('#test\\\\.1")` can't work; your quotes are mismatching.

Comment: I used <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: Who told you to use ``\\\\``? ``\\`` is what the docs say, and [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/5UhBJ/).

Comment: @Matt, sorry, my mistype, i edited the question.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that `"#test\\.1"` works but `'#'+'test\\.1'` doesn't. It's also a bit suspicious that you keep changing the code in the question --- what do you *actually* have that doesn't work? Could you show a complete example that you have confirmed that doesn't work?

Comment: Purpose of editing after each comment the question???

Comment: @Juhana: I update the question again, sorry for this inconvenient. And thank you very much for your help

Comment: @roasted: yup, sorry for the continuous changing. I didn't ask the right question that concentrate on my point.

Comment: Yeah, it's generally best to show what you have, not some over-simplification. You didn't actually have `$('#'+'test\\.1')`, you had `$('#'+id)`. (And as a side note, that regex is completely unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two backslashes to escape the period:

```
$('#test\\.1');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HzfLN/)

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

Comment: thank you MrCode. I used your demo to update my code and show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatching quotes in the first example. This simply will not work. You need to change:

```js
$('#test\\.1")
```

To:

```js
$('#test\\.1') /* or */
$("#test\\.1")
```

As for your other example. What you currently have [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/up5dQ/).

```js
$('#test\\.1')
$('#' + 'test\\.1')
```

Comment: thanks guy, all works fine. it's was my bug in my code, i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could use:

```
$('[id="test.1"]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uWKXJ/

Comment: thank you for the recommended way. I have more choice to think ^^